# Where's the rep difference thing?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, recent-activity

So on my Ipad(Safari), seemingly there is no indicator of how much rep I lost/earned from a post of mine as seen here:

[image: some-image]

So from the bottom, nicael got 10 rep for Post A, 10 more rep for Post B, 25 rep from Post C, and a mystery amount of rep for Post D which can be negative or positive. So how come I can't see how much rep he got/lost in the Reputation section (not the tab) in his activity page? Should I blame caching?

EDIT: Oops! I forgot that this is @nicael's activity page... ;)

Comment: So are you a sock of @nicael's , since the url you're on is apparently his activity profile https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael?tab=topactivity , but I can't repro this.

Comment: wait... this is nicael's profile...? YOU'RE A SOCK!??

Comment: That rep change belong to the questions on its **right side**, not left side. We never had rep change in the Answers section and should not have.

Comment: @Dronehinge LOL - I was 7 seconds late :P

Comment: @Dro yeah, something here smells of `@nic`... ;)

Comment: No no no, I am not a sock.

Comment: I promise you 100 percent I am not a sock.

Comment: LOL Of course he isn't, @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ :D

Comment: Still, no bug here. You got the numbers wrong.

Comment: "Why is any object we don't understand always called a thing?"

Comment: That is just how we people are @James. If you do know what it is called, feel free to edit my title.

Comment: That graph on the left is *impressively* nonmonotonic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You obviously can't, regardless of this profile being yours or someone else's ;)

This happens because the sum of recent rep is zero - in this case looks like recent rep for that question is calculated of 2 upvotes and 5 downvotes. And this rep isn't necessary summed for only today - hence the confusion.